# Wordpress - Best way to differentiate between Blog Posts and News Posts

Tags: wordpress

I am implementing a clients website in wordpress that has both news and blog posts. ***The homepage is satic page but the nav bar has the links to two different types of posts - NEWS AND BLOGS.***  Though both are exactly same however they are to be made accessible entirely separate from each other through the navigation bar.

Now ***I would like to know what is the best possible way to differentiate between the two in the admin panel:***
I mean i can create custom post types for either one or for both the types or on the other hand create no custom post type but just a taxonomy to divide the two into different parts as news posts and blog posts. Also I think I can use the custom field option to differentiate between the two...

**Kindly keep in mind that the news and blog posts will be made by the client himself...**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going with this train of thought

> Kindly keep in mind that the news and blog posts will be made by the client himself

I think that the best option would be to create a custom post type for "news" and leave the standard blog posts unchanged.

As you can see in the official [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types). Once you create a custom post type, a new top-level option will be created in the admin panel.

Which would allow for the following use scenarios:

- Posts > Add New
- Posts > All Posts
- News > Add New
- News > All News

Keeping the taxonomies out of this is also a good idea. Because that would allow you to keep them meaningful and share them among different post types.
e.g: clicking on "open source" category would show a list of "posts" and "news" related to that particular topic.

This [yoast](http://yoast.com/custom-post-type-snippets/) article covers a few more advanced scenarios and how to manage them.

Using custom-fields would probably confuse the end user. Especially because there will be times where they forget to add the field altogether, and wonder why the post is not showing on the page at all.

hope this helps

J